# Ruby on Rails can't save image src scraped with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nokogiri, src

I'm trying to get the src value of an image (which is located on another website) with Nokogiri, save it in my database and use it to display this image in my view. But Rails raiseS this error message:

> Nil location provided. Can't build URI.

here is my code in controller:

```
def scrape

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(page_url))
items = doc.css("j-wrapper-content")
images = doc.css("div.j-img")

images.each do |image|
  link = image.css("img").attr('src').to_s
  @product.image_url = "https://www.jacadi.fr#{link}"
end

items.each do |item|
  @product.name = item.css("h1").text
  @product.price = item.css("j-prd-price p").text.to_f
end

@product.save! end
```

and my code in view:

```
<% if product.picture.attached? %>
  <%= image_tag(product.picture, class: "card-pict") %>
<% elsif %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: "card-pict") %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag("gift.png", class: "card-pict mini") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the page source, whether the src attribute is there? It might be they have some lazy loading mechanism, that relies on Javascript, so the src attribute might be empty.

Comment: Yes the src is present, I've tested to just display it as text in my view and it works. I think there is no lazy load on the website... I'll try with another site.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution ! There were two issues :

1. In the controller : The `.` were missing in front of the css selector so Nokogiri was unable to find them.
2. In the view I've added the `.present?` behind my `product.image_url` in my elsif statement.